# Object property assignment with mixed values in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

running into a flow problem and cannot figure out how to resolve.

best to describe with code:

```
   type Mytype = {
      propA?: string,
      propB?: number,
    };

    type myTypeProps = $Keys<typeof MyType>;

    const source : Mytype = {
       propA: 'hello',
       propB: 10,
    };

    const myFunc = (props: Array<myTypeProps>, ): Mytype => {
       const dest:Mytype = {};
       props.forEach(propType => {
         dest[propType] = source[propType]; 
          //Flow Error because of 
          //type mismatch: string cannot be assigned to number
       });
       return dest;
    }
```

Now although the props array is specified as type of myTypeProps Flow doesn't seem to recognize the fact that if I'm using the same key then the type should be matching already?

Alternatively, the following would work without problem:

```
       const dest:Mytype = {};
       dest['propA'] = source['propA'];
       dest['propB'] = source['propB'];
       return dest;
```

So being explicit about the key works but when the keys are parametrized it doesn't.

Any thoughts?